# Excel VBA: how to programmatically remove the marching ants after range.copy

Tags: vba, excel

I don't want to resort to SendKeys "{ESC}"

Comment: In case anyone else is confused "marching ants" refers to the animated dashed border that is shown around a range of cells after it is copied

Comment: @Nick: Is the copying done programatically or via the UI?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`application.cutcopymode = false`

Answer (score 5):

Try this code as an example.  The key line is '*Application.CutCopyMode = False*'

```
Sub Test()
    Range("A1").Copy
    MsgBox "View Marching Ants"
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```